# Anyone Know how to copying a division formula down a row to correspond with data in adjacent column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, division

I have a spread sheet that has data in to separate rows that I would like to divide. Since there are many cells in the row I was interest in knowing how to apply a division formula that corresponds to each cell as show below, down the entire new row witout copying the same formula.

```
A    B      New C    
12   6      =+A1/B1    
15   5      =+A2/B2    
26   4      =+A3/B3
```

With the new c row, I would like to know how to continue the sequence down the row without having to type this out individually.

Any help would be appreciated.

Paul

Comment: What's your question? Can't you just drag the formula down? Or...wait, are those rows, not columns? Is the data shown in your question the right representation?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for how to auto-fill.  See [this link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Fill-data-automatically-in-worksheet-cells-74e31bdd-d993-45da-aa82-35a236c5b5db) and search for the heading "Fill formulas into adjacent cells"

Answer (score 0):

I guess your question is how to fill the formula throughout the column range,

Enter the formula in just one cell.

`=A1/B1`

and double click the fill handle. This will copy the formula for the complete range of data.